# How to reload section when there is only one row in section [Xamarin.iOS]?

Tags: uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have 1 row in section of UITableView and I want to remove that row trying to update table then it gives this exception:

> NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: attempt to delete and reload
> the same index path (<NSIndexPath: 0x60000021a020> {length = 2, path =
> 1 - 9223372036854775807})

Code:

```cs
public void DeleteContact(NSIndexPath indexPath, UserData userData)
{
    DatabaseService.DeleteItem(userData.ID);

    listData();

    ListView.Source = new TableSource(_itemdata, OnAddButtonClick, this);

    ListView.BeginUpdates();

    NSIndexPath[] rowsToReload = new NSIndexPath[]
    {
         NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(indexPath.Row, indexPath.Section)
    };

    var numberOfRowsInSection = ListView.NumberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.Section);

    if (numberOfRowsInSection == 1)
    {
        ListView.ReloadSections(NSIndexSet.FromIndex(indexPath.Section), UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade);
        ListView.DeleteSections(NSIndexSet.FromIndex(indexPath.Section), UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade);
        ListView.EndUpdates();
    }
    else
    {
        ListView.ReloadSections(NSIndexSet.FromIndex(indexPath.Section), UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade);
        ListView.EndUpdates();
    }
}

public void listData()
{
   List<UserData> listData = DatabaseService.GetAll();
   var sorted = listData.OrderBy(item => item.Name).ToList();
   _itemdata = sorted;
}
```

**Then I have tried to update table only without deleting section:**

```cs
ListView.ReloadSections(NSIndexSet.FromIndex(indexPath.Section), UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade);
ListView.EndUpdates();
```

With this it gives this exception:

> NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: attempt to insert section 1
> but there are only 1 sections after the update

In last I have tried to call ListView.ReloadData(); but this also not updates UITableView.

Anyone know how to achieve this?